# How to understand new operator overloading？

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

For `"+"` operator overloading, it is pretty easy to understand. `c = c1.operator+(c2)` is function notation, `c = c1 + c2` is operator notation.
However, I just couldn't understand `new` operator overloading. In the following code:
Please tell me what happened when processing `student * p = new student("Yash", 24);` Why `void * operator new(size_t size)` is called. And why size is `28` when entering `operator new(size_t size)`.

```
// CPP program to demonstrate 
// Overloading new and delete operator 
// for a specific class 
#include<iostream> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

using namespace std; 
class student 
{ 
    string name; 
    int age; 
public: 
    student() 
    { 
        cout<< "Constructor is called\n" ; 
    } 
    student(string name, int age) 
    { 
        this->name = name; 
        this->age = age; 
    } 
    void display() 
    { 
        cout<< "Name:" << name << endl; 
        cout<< "Age:" << age << endl; 
    } 
    void * operator new(size_t size) 
    { 
        cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl; 
        void * p = ::new student(); 
        //void * p = malloc(size); will also work fine 
    
        return p; 
    } 

    void operator delete(void * p) 
    { 
        cout<< "Overloading delete operator " << endl; 
        free(p); 
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    student * p = new student("Yash", 24); 

    p->display(); 
    delete p; 
}
```

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, `operator+(c1, c2)` is a much more common overload of the binary `+` operator than `c1.operator+(c2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments in

```
student * p = new student("Yash", 24);
```

are arguments to the `student` constructor, they are not passed to `operator new` whose only responsibility is to allocate enough memory for the `student` object.

In order to allocate enough memory for a `student` object `operator new` has to be told how much memory it needs to allocate, This is what `28` is, it's the value of `sizeof(student)`.

So your code

```
void * operator new(size_t size) 
{ 
    cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl; 
    void * p = ::new student(); 
    //void * p = malloc(size); will also work fine 

    return p; 
}
```

is actually incorrect because you are creating a `student` object which is not the responsibility of `operator new`. The commented out code that uses `malloc` is correct however.

To see this problem you should add the following

```
student(string name, int age) 
{ 
    cout<< "Constructor is called with " << name << " and " << age "\n" ; 
    this->name = name; 
    this->age = age; 
}
```

Now you will see that your bugged version calls two constructors for one object. This is because you are wrongly calling the constructor from `operator new`.

It is possible to explicitly pass arbitrary values from the user code to `operator new`. If you want to investigate this then look up *placement new*.

Comment: It would actually be really helpful to OP if you also put in the correct code for overloading new operator :) (OP is actually supposed to look that up on Google though...)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Well I mentioned that the commented out version with malloc is correct.

Comment: @fizzbuzz, I suggest you accept this answer. The answer is really good and solves your problem